# Upgrade from 4.1.5 to 4.2 (or any new version) fails

Tags: upgrade

I'm upgrading a very old CIVICRM version. I manage to get CIVI from 3.2 drupal 6 to 4.1.5 drupal 7.
However when I'm trying to upgrade from 4.1.5 to 4.2 or newer I'm getting several errors. Since this is old version is there anyone that got the same problem? What steps can solve the upgrade procedure?

Best regards
Eduardo

Comment: You probably need to paste the errors to help the community help you

Answer (score 1):

Enable debug and backtrace, it should make civicrm more verbose about why it fails.

It's a long time ago, but the internet has a good memory, if you can see the exact error message, searching for it should point you to someone else having had the same issue, and hopefully that did find a way to fix it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't easily google-find your specific error mesage for clues & since you're on a very old version (thus very few people are running into this) - Perhaps consider making it an export -> import into new CiviCRM on your Drupal7; gives you a great opportunity to also clean house;

Migrations from CiviCRM -> CiviCRM are typically relatively painless (compared to others) as lots of data will already be mapped;